The Error of Android AGP version and I have no idea how to fix it
When I open a file with Android studio this error message appears:
The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.3.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.2.1
It look like my AGP version didn't fits with the project. Please help me out how can I fix it.

What version of Android Studio are you using? Iguana is the first version that supports using AGP 8.3.

I use Hedgehog.
